# getJSON function not working on Bootstrap modal despite working on static page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, action

I have strange problem: I'm checking if email is already taken, which user is entering.

It is working in simple page, but when I'm trying to call it on modal - it doesn't work.

Here is jQuery:

```
 $('#user_email').focusout(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail.jsonr', { email: $('#user_email').val() }, function(data) 
    { $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); }//disable submit
   );
});
```

my HTML:

```
        <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
        <input class="btn" id="submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create an account">
```

my action and route to it:

```
def checkemail
 respond_to do |format|
   format.jsonr do
    if User.where(email: params[:email]).exists? 
      render :json => {
            :status  => :ok,
            :message => "Success!"
            }.to_json
     end
   end
  end
end

...route...
checkemail        /checkemail
```

also added mimetype

```
   Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :jsonr, %w( text/x-json )
```

but as I see in log it seems to be, that action isn't calling. However all the same things are working in other project.

Can someone tell me where can be the problem ?

Comment: Try removing the `http://127.0.0.1:3000` part. You probably got cross-domain issue.

Comment: @jdoe,hello again) it is working in simple page `$.getJSON('/checkemail.jsonr'`, but doesn't work on modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vote this answer down if you want, let me whip out the ajax ruby rails checklist.
Since it works on simple page and not modal, it has to be a javascript issue.

1) Make sure your jquery is in the $(document).ready() block.
2) Test your jquery listeners on   $('#user_email').  I'm not a fan of alerts() but use console.log("blah");

3) try a simple ajax request without jsonr response?

Thats all i gotta say.
Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer! I found problem - all because I have a lot of forms, that contains the same input id. I forgot about that)

Comment: It's always those that gets you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your modal is being done, but are you sure that your modal has access to the relevant jQuery function, is it included? Test that the jQuery focusout function is being run by sticking an alert("test"); or something in the function.

Comment: @Campbell, it seems to be not working `$('#user_email').focusout(function() {
    alert('super');
}` - no alert

Comment: Where is your HTML form located, and does that file have an `<%= javascript_include_tag "my_javascript_file" %>`?

Comment: it is located in devise/registrations/new. I'm running jQuery validation there, so yes it include javascript file.

Comment: tried different variants - none of them are working - `$('#user_email').click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});` - this too

Comment: one way or another, that jquery event handler isn't hooked to your form element, hence my suspicions about your include. whatever you do when you move your form from your "simple page" to your "modal", you're taking it out of the scope of your jquery function -- i believe.

Comment: I understood where is the problem - had many fields with same id `user_email`

Comment: ah .. that'll probably do it then.